# Allow and Disallow in Robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html says:

> Disallow: /help disallows both /help.html and /help/index.html

Now, google.com/robots.txt lists:

```
Disallow: /search  
Allow: /search/about
```

Upon running `robotparser.py`, it returns `false` for both the above cases in Googles `robots.txt`.

Would somebody please explain me, what's the use of `Allow` in `Allow: /search/about` as it would return a `false` based on the `Disallow` entry above it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module documentation for `robotparser` and its Python 3 counterpart, [`urllib.robotparser`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.robotparser.html?highlight=robotparser#module-urllib.robotparser), mention that they use the [original specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html). This specification does not have an `Allow` directive; that is a [non-standard extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Allow_directive). Some major crawlers support it, but you (obviously) don't have to support it to claim compliance.