# Robots.txt Behavior, when Allow: or Disallow: directives don't specify a matching pattern

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib, robots.txt

I'm working on a presentation on web scraping and I'm trying to explain parts of robots.txt.

Given the following section of [Wikipedia's robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/robots.txt), it appears that `IsraBot` is allowed to scrape `/` while `Mediapartners-Google*` is not.

```
# advertising-related bots:
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
Disallow: /

# Wikipedia work bots:
User-agent: IsraBot
Disallow:
```

This is validated by

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org'
rfp = urllib.robotparser.RobotFileParser(f'{url}/robots.txt')
rfp.read()

bots = ["*", "Mediapartners-Google*", "IsraBot", "gsa-garmin"]
for bot in bots:
    print(rfp.can_fetch(bot, f'{url}/'))
# True
# False
# True
# True
```

However, when I look at [Garmin's robots.txt](https://www.garmin.com/robots.txt), it looks like they're pretty open for scraping. They even comment that their intent is for all bots to be able to **scrape** with a few exceptions.

```
# Allow all agents to get all stuff
User-agent:  *
Disallow:

# ...except this stuff...

# pointless without POSTed form data:
Disallow: /products/comparison.jsp

# not for the general public:
Disallow: /dealerResource/*
Disallow: /lbt/*

User-agent: gsa-garmin
Allow: /
```

However, running the same code as above on Garmin's site, it does not appear to allow any bots to scrape.

```
url = 'https://www.garmin.com'
rfp = urllib.robotparser.RobotFileParser(f'{url}/robots.txt')
rfp.read()

bots = ["*", "Mediapartners-Google*", "IsraBot", "gsa-garmin"]
for bot in bots:
    print(rfp.can_fetch(bot, f'{url}/'))
# False
# False
# False
# False
```

I guess the main question is what is the difference between the two lines below (for either Disallow or Allow)? I read this as the first says nothing is disallowed while the second says '/' is disallowed.

```
Disallow:
Disallow: /
```

I am also perplexed as to why `rfp.can_fetch('gsa-garmin', 'https://www.garmin.com/')` would return `False`.

Is there a difference between these lines?

```
Disallow: 
Allow: /
```

Even answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198431/is-this-robots-txt-file-correct) suggests my understanding is correct, but the code says otherwise. Also answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547521/allow-and-disallow-in-robots-txt) state that the `Allow` directive is a [non-standard extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Allow_directive), but [`RobotFileParser.parse()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/urllib/robotparser.py#L80) appears to support it.

And if it's an error with Python, this was performed with Python 3.7.5